# Sum on simultaneous equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics, fractions

Solving this simultaneous equation is little bit hard.

The equation
$$\frac{1}{y-2} - \frac{1}{x+2}=\frac{1}{60}$$ and
$$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{60}.$$
How to solve it please explain.

Comment: It is: $(\frac{1}{y}-2)-(\frac{1}{x}+2)=\frac{1}{60}$ ? Or  $(\frac{1}{y-2})-(\frac{1}{x+2})=\frac{1}{60}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's
$$xy=62x-62y+244$$ and
$$xy=60y-60x,$$ which gives
$$62x-62y+244=60y-60x$$ or
$$y=x+2$$ and I hope the rest is smooth.

I got $(10,12)$ and $(-12,-10)$.

Answer (score 2):

Given equations: 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{y-2} - \dfrac{1}{x+2} = \dfrac{1}{60} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{1}{60} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

From (1), we have 
\begin{align}
& \dfrac{1}{y-2} - \dfrac{1}{x+2} = \dfrac{1}{60} \notag \\
\implies & \dfrac{(x + 2) - (y-2)}{(y-2)(x+2)} = \dfrac{1}{60} \notag \\
\implies & 60 x - 60 y +240 = xy +2y -2x -4 \tag{by cross multiplication} \\
\implies  & xy + 62y - 62 x -244 = 0 \tag{3}
\end{align}
Furthermore, from (2) we have 
\begin{align}
& \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{1}{60} \notag \\
\implies & \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{1}{60} + \dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{y + 60}{60 y} \notag \\
\implies & x = \dfrac{60y}{y + 60} \tag{4}
\end{align}
Putting the value of $x$ from (4) to (3) yields, 
\begin{align}
& \left( \dfrac{60 y}{y + 60}\right) \times y + 62 y - 62 \times \left( \dfrac{60 y}{y + 60}\right) - 244 = 0 \notag \\
\implies &60 y^{2} + 62 y(y + 60) - \left(62 \times 60\right) y - 244 (y + 60) = 0 \notag \\
\implies & 122 y^{2} - 244 y - (244 \times 60) = 0 \notag \\
\implies & y^{2} - 2y - 120 = 0 \notag \\
\implies & y^{2} - 12y + 10y - (12 \times 10) = 0 \notag \\
\implies & y (y - 12) + 10 (y - 12) = 0 \notag \\
\implies & (y + 10) (y - 12) = 0 \notag \\
\implies & y = -10, 12 \tag{5}
\end{align}
Using (4) and (5), the value of $x$ can be found as, 
\begin{align}
x = \dfrac{60 \times (-10)}{-10 + 60}, \, \dfrac{60 \times 12}{12 + 60} = -12, 10
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

from the second equation we get by multiplication with $$xy\ne 0$$
$$y-x=\frac{1}{60}xy$$ solving for $x$ we obtaine
$$x=\frac{y}{\frac{1}{60}y+1}=\frac{60y}{y+60}$$
plugging this in the first equation we obtain 8after symplifications
$$61y^2+122y+120=0$$
solving this we obtain
$$x=-12,y=-10$$ or $$x=10,y=12$$

Comment: You meant to write $y - x = \frac{1}{60}xy$.